# User form foreignkeyfield form not valid

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I was creating a post based website i want to show the author's name to show up in the post it works in the admin site when adding posts but when i try uploading a post from the site the form is not getting validated therefore it is not getting saved please help
model :

```
from django.conf import settings

class MemeImg(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    op = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Post_Img = CloudinaryField('Post')
```

forms :

```
class PostImg(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MemeImg
        fields = ['Title', 'op', 'Post_Img']
```

view :

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def post(request):
    func = data(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostImg(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
        form.op = request.user
        if form.is_valid():
            print('success')
            posts = form.save(commit=False)
            posts.op = request.user
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ')
        else:
            print("fail")
    form = PostImg(request)
    ctx = {
        'form': form,
        'url': func[0],
        'name': func[1],
        'date': func[2],
    }
    return render(request, 'Post.html', ctx)
```

and finally the post page template :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="container">
        {{ form.Title|materializecss }}
        <div class="file-field input-field">
            <div class="btn">
                <span>File</span>
                <input type="file">
            </div>
            <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                {{ form.Post_Img }}
                <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

If anymore code is required please comment it
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem come from the form instance which is instance=request.user, actually the instance is supposed to be the MemeImg object instance and not the user, that's making it not to save the image. So i have deleted the instance and also i don't know what you are using those extra context variable for    'url': func[0],'name': func[1], 'date': func[2] ?, so i deleted them too keep things simple. Now i think you should be able to save without any Issues.

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostImg(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('success')
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.op = request.user
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ')
        else:
            print("fail")
            form = PostImg(request.POST)
    ctx = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'Post.html', ctx)
```

Also your form had in it {{ form.Post_Img }} which i don't no what you are looking to accomplish with that variables?, the right way is doing {{ form.as_p }} or simply just calling the form like this {{ form }} so i have made the correction in you HTML
too.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="container">
        {{ form.Title|materializecss }}
        <div class="file-field input-field">
            <div class="btn">
                <span>File</span>
                <input type="file">
            </div>
            <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                {{ form }}
                <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks so much dude i would upvote you but i don't have enough reputation

Comment: You don't need reputation to mark an accepted answer and also to vote an answer you thought  was useful to  you! you are  welcome !

Comment: Mark accept the answer to let others benefit from the post if it help solve your problem!